# using subfolders in codeigniter causes problems

Tags: php, codeigniter, controllers, subdirectory

I am getting page not found error in my CI web app
I have 3 seperate sub-folders with controllers inside of them, admin, site, members. the structure looks like so.

```
- Controllers
--- Site
----- site.php <-- handles all general site pages
--- Members
----- dashboard.php <-- default controller to be called when no parameter is passed
----- products.php <-- handles all products request
--- Admin
---- dashboard.php <-- default controller to be called when no parameter is passed
---- members.php <-- handles all members request
```

I tried routing it in the routes.php file like this

```
// Admin - folder/controler/Method

$route['admin/(:any)'] = 'admin/admin/$1';
$route['admin'] = 'admin/dashboard/index'; 

$route['clients/(:any)'] = 'clients/$1';
$route['clients'] = 'clients/dashboard/index';

$route['(:any)'] = 'site/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'site/index';

$route['404_override'] = '';
```

What do I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
// Admin - folder/controler/Method

$route['default_controller'] = 'site';
$route['404_override'] = '';

$route['admin/(:any)'] = 'admin/admin/$1';
$route['admin'] = 'admin/dashboard'; 


$route['clients/(:any)'] = 'clients/$1';
$route['clients'] = 'clients/dashboard';



$route['(:any)'] = 'site/$1';
```

- get rid of method (`index`)
- different order
- let reserved routes on top

Order of routes is important, when CI finds the first valid route it won't do the other routes in the list.